# Run action for success after cake's DoesForEach

Tags: cakebuild

I'm using the [`DoesForEach`](https://cakebuild.net/docs/writing-builds/tasks/running-task-for-collections) alias to run a task for a collection.

I want to report/act on success.

I cannot do this because it would run after every item in the collection:

```cs
Task("A")
  .DoesForEach(GetFiles("**/*.txt"), (file) => {
    //...
    DoSomething();           // <---
  });
```

I cannot do this because it would run for failures too:

```cs
Task("A")
  .DoesForEach(GetFiles("**/*.txt"), (file) => {
    //...
  })
  .Finally(() => {
    DoSomething();           // <---
  });
```

How can I do this?

(A workaround is *to run a dependent task after this one* - i.e. `B->A` - but that is a messy way to do it... unless it's the only way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to what devlead said, you could also add multiple actions to a task, like this:

```cs
Task("Default")
.Does(() => 
{
   Information("This action runs first.");
}).DoesForEach(GetFiles("./**/*"), f => 
{
   Information("Found file: "+f);
}).Does(() => {
   Information("This action runs last.");
});
```

And then there is also the [finally block](https://cakebuild.net/docs/writing-builds/tasks/finally-block):

```cs
Task("Default")
    .Does(() =>
{
   Information("This action runs...");
})
.Finally(() =>
{
    Information("This action runs at the end, regardless of errors...");
});
```

Comment: That first code block is exactly what I needed, thanks Nils!

Comment: @lonix this is now documented at https://cakebuild.net/docs/writing-builds/tasks/defining-tasks

Comment: Thanks! The docs are of a really high quality.

Answer (score 2):

TaskSetup / TaskTeardown probably what you're looking for.

https://cakebuild.net/docs/writing-builds/setup-and-teardown#task-lifetime

```cs
TaskSetup(setupContext =>
{
    var message = string.Format("Task: {0}", setupContext.Task.Name);
    // custom logging
});

TaskTeardown(teardownContext =>
{
    var message = string.Format("Task: {0}", teardownContext.Task.Name);
    // custom logging
});
```

An example to group tasks in GitHub Actions

```cs
if (BuildSystem.GitHubActions.IsRunningOnGitHubActions)
{
    TaskSetup(context=> System.Console.WriteLine($"::group::{context.Task.Name.Quote()}"));
    TaskTeardown(context=>System.Console.WriteLine("::endgroup::"));
}
```

Documentation on task setup context definition here
https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core/ITaskSetupContext/

and teardown here
https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core/ITaskTeardownContext/

Comment: Thanks. Please correct me if I'm wrong but that is mainly for logging? Suppose I run a task for a collection, and I want to `DoSomething()` if the task succeeded - I would lose that info in the `TaskSetup/TearDown`? I can act after a task succeeds, but if it's a collection of tasks then I can't?

Comment: Teardown will execute regardless of success or not. So good for reporting,  the teardown context has a Successful,  ThrownException and Task property you can use to  determine which task and if successful https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core/ITaskTeardownContext/

Comment: Although it's effectively a workaround, that `ITaskTeardownContext` is a good "hook" for such functionality. (And it seems better than the workaround I mentioned above.) Very useful - thanks.